# Сделать, чтобы при переключении на QDialog появлялись оба окна?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qdialog

Есть окно `QMainWindow`, оно открывает второе окно типа `QDialog`.
Если я из `QDialog` любым способом переключусь на стороннее окно (для примера, обычный Блокнот), а потом обратно на `QDialog` - наверх перемесится только одно окно `QDialog`, и порядок окон станет таким: `QDialog -> Блокнот -> QMainWindow`.
Соответственно, если я закрою `QDialog`, фокус переместится на Блокнот, и придется вручную переключаться на `QMainWindow`.

Мне бы хотелось как то связать положение `QDialog` и `QMainWindow`, чтобы переключение на `QDialog` перемещало `QMainWindow` в порядке приложений к нему.

Вижу две возможности того, как можно сделать то, что мне бы хотелось:

1. В идеале при переключении на `QDialog` у меня возвращается исходное положение окон - я вижу на фоне `QMainWindow`, и поверх него отображается `QDialog`, если зажать `Alt` и ткнуть в `Tab` то в списке будет видно `QDialog -> QMainWindow -> Блокнот`.
2. Не идеально, но в целом тоже можно было бы активировать `QMainWindow` при закрытии `QDialog`.

PS Не очень уверен как это правильно сформулировать.
PPS Минимальный пример, запускаю под `Win10x64` через `PyCharm`, последовательность действий:

1. Запустить программу, нажать кнопку. Появляется второе окно, типа `QDialog`;
2. **Переключиться на любое окно, не принадлежащее программе** - Блокнот, браузер, и.т.п.;
3. Переключиться обратно именно на `QDialog`, `QMainWindow` не трогаем;
4. Закрыть `QDialog`, у меня фокус падает на окно из п.2;
5. А хочется, чтобы фокус оказался на `QMainWindow`. В идеале `QMainWindow` хотелось бы увидеть под `QDialog` еще на 3м шаге.

**ui_one_button.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(335, 187)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(254, 214, 188);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 335, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**dialog_one_button.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
```

**main_one_button.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from ui_one_button import Ui_MainWindow
from dialog_one_button import Ui_Dialog


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dialog = None
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onPBClicked)

    def onPBClicked(self):
        class My_dialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.setupUi(self)

        self.dialog = My_dialog()
        self.dialog.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: пожалуй что нужен пример. проверил в линуксе. с QFileDialog проблем нет

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev добавил пример, именно в этом примере у меня все именно так, как я описываю в последовательности действий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте главное окно, дочернему диалоговому окну в качестве родительского.

```
    def onPBClicked(self):
        class My_dialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
            def __init__(self, parent):
                super().__init__(parent)
                self.setupUi(self)

        self.dialog = My_dialog(self)
        self.dialog.exec()
```

Comment: Оно работает, спасибо!